# Fabric JS Why does it clear my canvas background

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have simple question :
I already have image in my canvas but when I use fabric to draw circle in this same canvas, it does clear my canvas.. why? How can I stop it?
I want to keep my canvas background as it is and then draw/sketch other shapes. Can someone help?
Please see attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work as intended because you are trying to combine native code with a library.
I think you should drop this code:

```
const img = document.getElementById("image_1");
var test_canvas = document.getElementById("test");
var test_canvas_ctx = test_canvas.getContext("2d");
test_canvas_ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,320,240);
```

fabric js does not know what you are trying to draw before it and when you call the sketch.renderAll() method everything that was drawn before is deleted and not drawn again, but what was added to fabric js, in your case it is a circle, is drawn again.

You need to add a picture to the fabric js, you can do it like this:

```
// add by src
fabric.Image.fromURL('image_1.jpg', function(img) {
    var another = img.set({ left: 150, top: 0});
    sketch.add(another);
});


// add by HTML element
var fabImage = new fabric.Image(document.getElementById("image_1"), {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    //width: 320,
    //height: 240
});
sketch.add(fabImage);

// add by src
var anotherFabImage = new fabric.Image();
anotherFabImage.set({left: 150, top: 50});
anotherFabImage.setSrc("image_1.jpg", function() {
    sketch.renderAll();
});
sketch.add(anotherFabImage);
```

You need to add fabric objects to fabric.canvas to get everything cleaned up and rendered correctly.

If the built-in features of fabric js aren't enough for you, you can add your custom classes and write your own render, drag and drop and other methods for them.

Comment: Hi Waff 
Many Thanks... please see my attached code snippet. Its simple... Please if you can help in next few hours as it is urgent for me now

Comment: Hi Waff
Actually that was just code to explain situation. Actually I am drawing fabric js circle and rectangle over video editor. So I load images in canvas and then use appendChile method to keep rect or circle over loaded image. It was better if I can draw circle over loaded images. I am using this editor https://github.com/bwasti/mebm  and drawing sketches over it

Comment: I think you should break images and anything drawn on top of them into groups or layers

Comment: Seems like that is what I can do only.... because fabric do not care about what my canvas already had. Anyway thanks for your suggestion and answering.

Comment: Hi Waff
can you tell me if we can use same canvas Id for creating multiple objects like var sketch= new fabric.Canvas('c'); and again in loop var sketch= new fabric.Canvas('c'); This gives problem ?

Comment: I think that new fabric.canvas will create 2 canvases top and bottom. But how will you pull them up? In any case, even if you create a canvas using document.createElement('canvas') and give it an id, you'll have to assign orders to them somehow. I think you can use the css property `z-index` and the higher the index the higher the element will be above the other one.